# How to manage association in my entity model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-8, windows-runtime, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a webapi that serves data to my windows8 metro application

I have a model Content that can have categories so beetwen Content and Category is m:n relation. I've created with my diagram (.edmx) and I've updated database. My model has ICollection field. In my xml (I read answer via browser in xml) I get empty tag 
I`ve populated db with data so I should have some categories there. What should I do to have them there or what should I provide you guys so you can tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Include()` method is the answer

I just Include("MyInclude") to the main object and it works great